# Kiam Uzi "ĝi" kaj ne uzi "ĝi"

Tags: word-usage

Kiam oni bezonas uzi "ĝi" kaj kiam ne?  Kiam ne estas ĝuste uzi tiun vorton?

En la angla, franca, ktp oni ofte uzas "ĝi" ("It", "Ce") kiel subjekton de frazo, kiam oni ne bezonas ĝin en Esperanto.

Ekzemple, "Ĝi pluvas" aŭ "Pluvas."  Mi scias, ke oni rajtas uzi "Pluvas". Ĉu ne estas ĝuste diri "Ĝi pluvas"? Kial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi trovis tion ĉi por ekspliki mian respondon de la ligilo, kiun Lumo5 metis.  Ĝi ankaŭ eksplikas tion, kion Joffysloffy eksplikis.

Tre dankon!
http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/tria.html

> Zamenhof iafoje uzis *ĝi* kiel superfluan duoblaĵon de subjekto aŭ objekto, kiam la vera subjekto aŭ objekto estis I-verbo. Li ankaŭ uzis iafoje *ĝi* kiel superfluan duoblaĵon de subjekto de *esti*, kiam la vera subjekto staris post *esti*. Tiu uzo komplete malaperis, kaj estas nuntempe rigardata kiel eraro:
>   *Por mi **ĝi** estis la plej kora ĝojo inciti la hundon.*<sup>Rt.19</sup> *Ĝi* rolas kiel subjekto, sed la vera subjekto estas *inciti la hundon*. Oni forlasu *ĝi*.
>   ***Ĝi*** estis varmega posttagmezo.<sup>Rt.83</sup> La vera subjekto estas *varmega posttagmezo*. Oni forlasu *ĝi*.
>   En kelkaj lingvoj oni iafoje uzas pronomon similan al *ĝi* kiel malplenan subjekton, kiu reprezentas nenion ajn. La koncernaj verboj vere estas sensubjektaj. En Esperanto oni ne uzu *ĝi* ĉe tiaj sensubjektaj verboj: *Hodiaŭ pluvas.* *Estos varme tie.*

Answer (score 7):

Se *ĝi* ne havas iun ajn signifon, vi ellasu tiun vorton. En la frazoj, kiujn vi priskribas, estas bona testo por determini, ĉu *ĝi* estas ellasenda: Demandu “kio `<enmetu verbon>`?”; se la respondo estas malklara aŭ ne havas sencon, vi ellasu *ĝi*. Ekzemple, se vi skribus “Ĝi pluvas.”, vi demandu vin: “Kio pluvas?”. La respondon vi ne povas doni, ĉar tio, kio estas *ĝi* en tiu frazo, estas tute ne klara, ĉar *nenio pluvas*; la pluvo simple falas memstare. Do estu simple “Pluvas.”.

Answer (score 1):

La vorto **ĝi** nur estas pronomo por besto aŭ aĵo.

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/gxi.html#gxi.0

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/tria.html

Ni ne diras "ĝi pluvas".